# error: attribute behaviour_peekHeight not found

Tags: android, android-studio, bottom-sheet

```
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"

app:behavior_hideable="true"

app:behaviour_peekHeight="56dp"
```

I'm trying to make a bottom sheet. When I run my program it shows this:

```
error: attribute behaviour_peekHeight  not found
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
app:behavior_peekHeight="56dp"
```

instead of:

```
app:behaviour_peekHeight="56dp"
```